# SQL Error in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1054

I have the tables

```
Department: id, name
Employee: id, departmentId, name, surname
```

departmentId is a foreign key referencing Department(id)
The Query:

```
SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE Employee.departmentId = Department.id;
```

returns the error "Unknown column Department.id in where clause"

I can't place this error. How do i fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Department is sort of coming out of nowhere in you query, you might want to conider http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to actually include the `department` table

```
SELECT * 
FROM Employee 
JOIN Department
   ON Employee.departmentId = Department.id;
```

This uses explicit `JOIN` syntax which is ANSI standard. You should refrain from implicit joins.

Comment: thank you.. how silly of me!!..

Answer (score 0):

That's because your `Department` table is not in your FROM clause. Include it.

```
select *
from Employee, Department
where Employee.departmentId = Department.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't including Department in your from clause....

`SELECT * FROM Employee, Department WHERE Employee.departmentId = Department.id;`

Comment: Or use a join, which is probably more flexible

Comment: That is a join, just not using the JOIN syntax

Comment: .. and ANSI standard.

Comment: @DanielDiPaolo Huh? Then what do you call this?

Comment: Recommending poor coding practices asuch as implicit joins is a bad idea.

Comment: OPs using MySQL, which is hardly ANSI standard.